# Displaying a db table row that matches WP post-id into an html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, wordpress

Need some guidance. I've built a volleyball club site in Wordpress ([http://goo.gl/2Y0j10][1]) and we've solicited player profile data from parents that I'm capturing in a Google form/spreadsheet, saving as a .csv then importing into a 'profiles' table. http://dev.tavhouston.com/profile-db-table.jpg

I'm adding some code to the player template file that will display the data in an html table, based on a match of the WP post-id. I determined all the player's post-ids and included them in the first column of the "profiles" table, called "post_id", and set it as Primary. So if you open a player page with postid-1566 for example, the row in 'profiles' with a post_id of 1566 should be displayed.

What I've got now pulls up everyone's profile data because of the SELECT * query. I'm trying to change the syntax of the query to DISTINCT so it looks for the specific row in the profile table that has the same post-id number as the player page you're on.

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
//  $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->profiles" ) );
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM profiles" ) );

    foreach ( $result as $print )   {

      echo '<h6>Playing Experience </h6><p>' . $print->PlayingExperience.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Previous Clubs </h6><p>' . $print->PreviousClubs.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Athletic Awards & Accolades</h6><p>' . $print->AwardsAccolades.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Fondest Volleyball Memory</h6><p>' . $print->FondestMemory.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Best Finish</h6><p>' . $print->BestFinish.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Online Video</h6><p>' . $print->OnlineVideo.'</p>';

      echo '<h3>Profile Details</h3>';

//      echo '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"]';
//      echo '[content_protector password=&quot;xxxxxxx&quot; cookie_expires=&quot;0&quot; identifier=&quot;xxx&quot;]';

// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
//      echo do_shortcode( '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"] Private Info  [/content_protector]' );
      echo do_shortcode( '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"]' );
      echo '<h2>' . $print->FirstName.' ' . $print->LastName.' </h2>';
      echo '<table class="profile center">';
      echo '<tr><td>Team </td><td>' . $print->Team.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>First Name </td><td>' . $print->FirstName.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Nickname </td><td>' . $print->Nickname.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Middle Name </td><td>' . $print->MiddleName.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Last Name </td><td>' . $print->LastName.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Height </td><td>' . $print->Height.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Position </td><td>' . $print->Position.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Birthday </td><td>' . $print->Birthday.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>School </td><td>' . $print->School.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Grade </td><td>' . $print->Grade.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Class </td><td>' . $print->Class.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Commitment </td><td>' . $print->Commitment.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Standing Reach </td><td>' . $print->Reach.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Block Touch </td><td>' . $print->Block.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Approach Jump </td><td>' . $print->Approach.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>GPA (Unweighted) </td><td>' . $print->GPA_Unweighted.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>GPA (Weighted) </td><td>' . $print->GPA_Weighted.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Class Rank </td><td>' . $print->ClassRank.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>ACT Scores </td><td>' . $print->ACT_Score.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>SAT Scores </td><td>' . $print->SAT_Score.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parents / Guardians </td><td>' . $print->Parents.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 1 Email </td><td>' . $print->ParentEmail1.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 2 Email </td><td>' . $print->ParentEmail2.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Address </td><td>' . $print->Address.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>City, State, Zip </td><td>' . $print->City.', ' . $print->State.', ' . $print->Zip.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Your Cell # </td><td>' . $print->YourCell.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 1 Cell # </td><td>' . $print->ParentCell1.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 2 Cell # </td><td>' . $print->ParentCell2.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Home Phone </td><td>' . $print->HomePhone.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Interest in Beach Volleyball? </td><td>' . $print->BeachInterest.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Beach Volleyball experience? </td><td>' . $print->BeachExperience.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Next ACT/SAT date </td><td>' . $print->NextACTSATdate.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Favorite Subjects </td><td>' . $print->FavoriteSubjects.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Desired Area of Study </td><td>' . $print->DesiredMajor.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Desired Level of Play </td><td>' . $print->DesiredPlayingLevel.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>State of College Preference </td><td>' . $print->CollegePreference.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Size of School </td><td>' . $print->SchoolSize.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Contacting schools? </td><td>' . $print->ContactingSchools.'</td></tr>';
      echo '</table>';
//      echo '[/content_protector]';
      echo do_shortcode( '[/content_protector]' );

  }
?>
```

Not sure if I'm approaching this the best way, but feel I'm close. I think the solution is somewhere in this example but I can't get it to work.

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id AND
  $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
  $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
```

I'm also having trouble executing the closing tag of the "content_protector" shortcode. I can get it started at the top with the do_shortcode, but everything past that to the end needs to be inside that [/content_protector] and it doesn't work adding the last half of that line to the bottom. Any suggestions? Is there a way to nest everything between the shortcode?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: so what are your issues? google wpdb for a start

Comment: I need to display the matching row of data in my custom table that has the same PlayerID as the post-id of the WP post. I determined the post-id of each player's page and entered that same number in my custom table under PlayerID. So if the post-id of the player page pulled up is 2718, I need to display the row of data with the PlayerID of 2718 in an html table. Seems like I need a PHP If/Then statement of some kind.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way(core PHP), first of all you should use WordPress syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way(core PHP), first of all you should use WordPress syntax. Google it for creating **custom post types** and try creating custom post type for players. Then try to write a script that inserts all the players using WordPress code. Refer below link for the same
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post and for creating custom post type you can do it using code or you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: You are correct. I edited the original question with what I've come up with so far.